# Enable Virt Machine Graphics in qemu-system-aarch64 running on Windows X86-64 Host

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, qemu, arm64

I am emulating an aarch64 platform using qemu. I have successfully installed ubuntu server for arm64 (16.04 LTS). I want to enable machine graphics for the 'virt' machine type. I have followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM#virt_machine_graphics). However, that does not work.

Apart from the graphics, all else works. Also, I have installed mint desktop on the Ubuntu installation. All I require is the graphics display, please.

Here's my code:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -cpu cortex-a53 -M virt -m 2048 -device virtio-gpu-pci -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=QEMU_EFI.img -drive if=pflash,file=varstore.img -drive if=none,file=ubuntu.img,id=hd0
```

When I run this, I get a virtio-gpu display but once the bios loads, it shows "Guest disabled display". Could you please point me to what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 host with Ubuntu 20.04 image.

But there is no such issue with CentOS 8 image which can be find here https://cloud.centos.org/centos/8/aarch64/images/

So it can be related to image software or settings.
You can access running VM via `virsh console vmName` to try change something inside VM.

And also it can be a bug in QEMU :-) - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1661288

Answer (score 0):

you can perhap's try multiple video devices, and after boot select them in the view menu

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -smp 8 -m 4G -cpu cortex-a72 -serial stdio -bios /usr/share/edk2/aarch64/QEMU_EFI.fd -drive if=none,file=./Mageia-8-rpi-aarch64-noDE.img,format=raw,id=hd -device qemu-xhci -device usb-storage,drive=hd -boot menu=on -device qxl -display gtk,gl=on -device virtio-gpu-pci -writeconfig rpi4
```